# Cant get product MSRP price in custom module

Tags: magento2

I need to show MSRP price in a custom module template, but I cant get it.

I have **Magento\Catalog\Model\Product** model and $**product->getMsrp()** or **$product->getData('msrp')** does not return value (NULL).

The product exists and other basic data (like id, name etc) too.

Where might be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution, in block file:

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    ...
) {
    ...

    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}


public function getMsrpPrice($id)
{
    $product = $this->productRepository->getById($id);
    return $product->getMsrp();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code for msrp display.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
       $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(14);
       echo "<pre>"; print_r($product->getData());
       echo "Msrp :".$product->getMsrp());
```

[image]

[image]